# PHP json_decode - deal with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file using PHP and json_decode, however I'm having difficulting doing this when the JSON returned is namespaced. For example:

```
$json_ouput = json_decode($json);

foreach ( $json_ouput->feed as $feed) {

   /*
     Here is the problem, $feed contains a namespaced key
     $feed->ab:test->value // Does not work :(
   */
}
```

Whats the best solution here?

Comment: `%json_output`? What is `%` doing there? Can you show us some of your JSON that you're working with?

Comment: replace % with $ and try again!

Answer (score 4):

Same as always.

```
$feed->{'ab:test'}->value
```

Answer (score 0):

Much in the same way you would remove ambiguity between a variable and surrounding string characters, you can use `{` and `}` to patch together part of an accessor:

```
$json = '{"feed":[{"ab:test":{"value":"foo"}},{"ab:test":{"value":"bar"}}]}';
$json_output = json_decode( $json );

foreach ( $json_output->feed as $feed ) {

  // Outputs: foo bar
  print_r( $feed->{'ab:test'}->value );

}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/MYYwOJj2